# Some Confusion on Harmonic Map

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am stuck at **Corollary** $(3.4)$ on page $22$ in monograph *Selected Topics in Harmonic Maps* written by James Eells and Luc Lemaire.

**Corollary** Let $\phi:M,g\to N,h$ be harmonic and suppose $\text{Ricci}^M\geq0$ and $\text{Riem}^N\leq0$. Then $\phi$ is totally geodesic.

In its proof, authors use two results, and I am confused with them:

- One result is $\int_M \triangle|d\phi|^2v_g=0$. I guess this may follow **Stoke's Theorem**, but why is $\triangle|d\phi|^2v_g$ an exact form?
- Another is $\langle d\phi\cdot\text{Ricci}^M e_s,d\phi\cdot e_s\rangle\geq0$. We have $\text{Ricci}^M\geq0$, but we don't have $d\phi$ is a Riemannian immersion. So how do we have the result?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

---

Update $2016/2/24~10:41~\text{China}$

I have found the first result's proof. We will have $\int_M \triangle f_2~v_g=0$ by the **Green's Identity**
$$\int_Mf_1 \triangle f_2~v_g=\int_M\langle\text{grad}f_1,\text{grad}f_2\rangle v_g-\int_{\partial M}f_1Nf_2~v_g$$, which let $f_1=1$ and $\partial M$ is empty. And this can be found in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifold*.

---

Update $2016/2/24~14:14~\text{China}$

The $\{e_s\}$ is an orthonormal basis at the point under consideration on $M$, which can be find on page $22$.

Comment: In your second question, what is $e_s$? (Also, use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ respectively, instead of greater and less than signs.)

Comment: The way I like to think about Q1 is that $\Delta f  = div \nabla f$, so it's the derivative of a 1-form (gradient co-vector). The volume form $\nu_g$ can dualize $\nabla f$ into an $(n-1)$-form, hence $\Delta f \nu_g$ is the d of an $(n-1)$-form. In coordinates, $\Delta f = d( \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \hat{d x_i} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n)$.

Comment: @JohnJiang It is really nice. Thank you.